# firebase push notification on specific user by web app in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am trying to follow host by user, so I want to get notification for particular user not for other user. backend node.js I am getting device token and saving it in local database I am getting the notification but only for one user. how I can manage for other users.. please help me.

Comment: What you can do is make use of the realtime db or the firestore to store the collection of device tokens under particular userId. What I mean by that is a particular user would have multiple device tokens under its user Id. Then you need to simply fetch those tokens, iterate over them and send the notification.

Comment: Thanks a lot, token is changes every time can i store it like - {userId:123, token_ID:{'xxxxx','xxxxxxx','xxxxx'}}, i have to check for userid have any token or not if yes then i have to send notification,.... can you please Explain more. also if you have any sample code for that please share..

Comment: Yes, you can store multiple tokens for a particular userId. I would try to post the code for the same sometime today.

Comment: thanks for your support, yes I am storing multiple tokens for single userid . now what to do. if possible please share some code.

Comment: some body please help me.

Comment: Hey man, sorry for the delay, You can check this [link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js).